# Keycloak deactivate Kerberos auth without been auth

Tags: keycloak, kerberos

I'm trying to use Keycloak in order to success a login configuration with Kerberos. (Which is a big failure)
I've made a mistake which is Kerberos : Required.

In other word I opened *Authentication* > *Select Browser* > *Requirement* : **Required** on Kerberos

So I can't connect anymore, I got a "**Invalid username or password**" when logging on "http://localhost:8080/auth"

Has someone had an issue to resolve this without deleting and reconfiguring the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something which help me a lot. I solved my problem so, i will explain how

I've used in my **bin** directory : kcadmin.bat (or .sh)
Opened in a CMD

Login with kcadmin

```
kcadm.bat config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin
```

Next, i get the ID i need to update the flow (master) :

```
kcadmin.bat get authentication/flows/{FLOW}/executions
```

Next, i put in a JSON file `{"id":"ID_of_my_flow", "requirement":"ALTERNATIVE"}`
Save my file and finaly just wrote

```
kcadmin.bat update authentication/flows/master/executions -r REALM -f myfile.json
```

Thanks.

Comment: for future visitors , {FLOW} is the alias of the flow and "ID_of_my_flow" should be the execution ID